# Positioning something to the right of the browser using the relative position

Tags: css, position

I have to use the

```css
position: relative
```

in order to have a scroll bar appear in case of overflow (scroll bars apparently don't work when using the fixed position).

But by using relative, my inline block will appear in the middle of the page, and I can't position it 30px to the right on every screen size. Is there any solution for this?

My code right now:

```css
#main_wrap 
{
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y top left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 240px;
    position: relative;
}

#main
{
    position: relative;
    width: 680px;
    padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
    font: normal 14px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Another solution I would be fine with is when I can have a scrollbar while using the fixed position.

Maybe a dumb question but I'm not that experienced with this subject :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a WordPress theme, so I can't see the HTML, I guess.

Comment: Right click, show source.

Comment: Here is the HTML: http://pastie.org/private/jcolkrrjttochggkaig#35